# popping up dialog from a service also pops up main activity

Tags: android-intent

I'm working on an app with three Contexts:

All the MainActivity does is to start and stop the MonitorService, and display some user instructions.

The MonitorService is registered to receive changes in the ringer volume, and if it detects a change in volume, it pops up a ConfirmActivity.

The ConfirmActivity pops up an AlertDialog inside a DialogFragment to ask if the volume change was intended, and resets the volume if the user doesn't confirm the change.

The problem I'm seeing is that if the MainActivity is in the Stopped state, when the the ConfirmActivity starts, the MainActivity also gets restarted and resumed.  When the dialog is dismissed, the MainActivity remains visible.  I find this unexpected and disconcerting.  If the MainActivity has been destroyed, the ConfirmActivity works as expected.

Can anyone shed light on why starting the ConfirmActivity also restarts the MainActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android keeps track of which activities of your app have been used in what order, and when the app comes to the foreground it brings all of those activities with it, so if you had a MainActivity open that the user navigated away from, then you created a ConfirmActivity, the MainActivity will be just behind the ConfirmActivity.

To solve this, look at the flags that you can specify in an Intent when starting your activities.  There are several that affect how the stack of activities are handled; I think you probably want to use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK).